# problem with Custom scrollbar plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

Here's the source of the plugin:
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

And here's my page, it's not finished yet:
XXX

When I scroll down both divs scroll together!
I know nothing about jQuery and java, can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two `<div>` elements with the same `id` attribute, this:

```
<div id="mcs4_container">
```

appears twice in your HTML. Your `id` attributes have to be unique within each page. The solution is to change on of them to (for example):

```
<div id="mcs6_container">
```

And this to your jQuery:

```
$("#mcs6_container").mCustomScrollbar("vertical", 200, "easeOutCirc", 1.25, "fixed", "yes", "no", 0);
```

You could also replace your `#mcs4_container` binding to this to bind them both at once:

```
$('#mcs4_container, #mcs6_container').mCustomScrollbar("vertical", 200, "easeOutCirc", 1.25, "fixed", "yes", "no", 0);
```

Could also be just a copy and paste error. I notice that you have several "mcs*_container" `<div>`s mentioned in your jQuery.

Comment: thank u sooo much ! but it looks like there's something wrong when i scroll the second div http://glamorous.p2h.info/ee/ =(

Comment: @emoo: I think you just need to change the position parameters for the scroller you attach to `#mcs6_container`; the second scroller seems to work, it is just in the wrong place.

Comment: hi, it's been over a month and i still have the same problem. but i found something; when i replace the gallery div with any text, the scroll works! i want to fix it and keep the gallery div in the same time, can you plz help me

Comment: @emoo: Do you have a live example of your problem? Is it still at http://glamorous.p2h.info/ee/ ?

Comment: @emoo: I think your `<div>` nesting might be messed up in the lower one. Trying removing the `<div class="work">`, copy `<div class="updates">`, change the `id` in the copy to `mcs6_container`, and then replace the text in the copy with your `<ul>`. You also don't have a `clearfix` CSS class and that's probably why the list is overflowing the `<div>`. I don't know why it is scrolling backwards, a minimal example of the problem on jsfiddle.net would be helpful.

Comment: @emoo: That jsfiddle has a lot of extraneous and broken stuff in it. I'd like to help you but I'm not going to wade through several pages HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. If you can provide a **minimal** example of the broken scroller then I'll have a look, my minimal I mean just enough HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to demonstrate the problem and no more.

Comment: @emoo: Nice. Try adding `#gallery { overflow: hidden; }` to the CSS.